# StableDiffusionPipeline always producing empty picture, probably because of `safety_checker=None

Tags: huggingface-transformers

My code below always producing empty image, no matter how I change the prompt. The .ckpt file is already downloaded and placed at the same folder as the .py file.

```
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline

pipeline = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_single_file(
    "./v2-1_768-ema-pruned.ckpt"
)
pipeline.to("cpu")

prompt = "a photo of a knight riding a horse on icy lake"
image = pipeline(prompt).images[0]
image.save("result.png")
print("result.png created");
```

The error / warning:

> You have disabled the safety checker for <class 'diffusers.pipelines.stable_diffusion.pipeline_stable_diffusion.StableDiffusionPipeline'> by passing `safety_checker=None`. Ensure that you abide to the conditions of the Stable Diffusion license and do not expose unfiltered results in services or applications open to the public. Both the diffusers team and Hugging Face strongly recommend to keep the safety filter enabled in all public facing circumstances, disabling it only for use-cases that involve analyzing network behavior or auditing its results. For more information, please have a look at https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers/pull/254 .
> C:\Users\yohan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\diffusers\configuration_utils.py:135: FutureWarning: Accessing config attribute `requires_safety_checker` directly via 'StableDiffusionPipeline' object attribute is deprecated. Please access 'requires_safety_checker' over 'StableDiffusionPipeline's config object instead, e.g. 'scheduler.config.requires_safety_checker'.

The question:
How can I set safety_checker?

I've tried:

```
pipeline = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_single_file(
    "./v2-1_768-ema-pruned.ckpt",
    safety_checker=1
)
```

but doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: turned out safety_checker is not expecting boolean value. Final working code:

```
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline
from diffusers.pipelines.stable_diffusion import StableDiffusionSafetyChecker #NEWLY ADDED

pipeline = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_single_file(
    "./v2-1_768-ema-pruned.ckpt",
    safety_checker=StableDiffusionSafetyChecker.from_pretrained("CompVis/stable-diffusion-safety-checker"), #MODIFIED
)
pipeline.to("cpu")

prompt = "a photo of a knight riding a horse on icy lake"
image = pipeline(prompt).images[0]
image.save("result.png")
print("result.png created");
```